# Cannot update 2 different tables in a dash dashboard page

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a dash page that contains a table.
From a callback, I can update the info inside the table based on a datepicker or a filter from a dropdown.

```
@app.callback(
    Output('table_web', 'data'),
    [Input(component_id='datepickerrange', component_property='start_date'),
     Input(component_id='datepickerrange', component_property='end_date'),
     Input(component_id='my_button', component_property='n_clicks')],
    [State(component_id='table_dropdown_web', component_property='value')]
)
```

My problem appears when I want to add another table, that represent something else, and I want to filter that table with another callback, with it's own input.

But I cannot figure it out how can I declare the 2 callbacks for the 2 tables so the first callback adresses the first table, and the second callback to call the second table.

I tried something like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('table_teste', 'data_table1'),
    [Input(component_id='datepickerrange', component_property='start_date'),
     Input(component_id='datepickerrange', component_property='end_date'),
     Input(component_id='my_button_2', component_property='n_clicks')],
)
def create_table_1(start_date, end_date, n):
    # code
    return data_table1

@app.callback(
    Output('table_web_utm', 'data_table2'),
    [Input('my_button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('my_txt_input', 'value')]
)
def create_table_2(n, value):
    code
    return data_table2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out.
In case someone has the same problem.

I should have named the output in the callbacks and in the return of the functions with "data".

```
@app.callback(
    Output('table_teste', 'data'),
    [Input(component_id='datepickerrange', component_property='start_date'),
     Input(component_id='datepickerrange', component_property='end_date'),
     Input(component_id='my_button_2', component_property='n_clicks')],
)
def create_table_1(start_date, end_date, n):
    # code
    return data

@app.callback(
    Output('table_web_utm', 'data'),
    [Input('my_button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('my_txt_input', 'value')]
)
def create_table_2(n, value):
    code
    return data
```